# How do I inject a mock into the Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, mocking

I would like to arrange for a Spring instance object to be a Mock instead of the normally constructed instance in order to complete an integration test.

The object being mocked is not injected by Spring into a member variable but rather is accessed by querying the Spring context. An example (for reference):

```
class Service {
    public void doIt() {
        Helper helper = new Helper();
        helper.doIt();
    }
}

class Helper {
    public void doIt() {
        BeanFactory factory = getBeanFactory(); // A function to get the bean factory
        Target target = (Target)factory.getBean("target");
        target.doIt();
    }
}

class Target {
    public void doIt() {
        // Something interesting.
    }
}
```

I would like to Mock Target in order to verify that a call to Service.doIt() calls Target.doIt().

The instance of Helper is dynamic, that is Helper is not a Spring object and only exists for a short period of time as a link between these two interfaces.

We are using a (large) spring xml file for configuration, so multiple configurations for testing is best avoided.

How can I mock Target so that the Mock is retrieved from the Spring Bean factory?

Comment: Where is `getBeanFactory()` method?

Comment: getBeanFactory() is irrelevant. Assume getBeanFactory returns the appropriate Spring BeanFactory for the application.

Comment: Are you using some mocking framework, like `mockito`?

Comment: Yes, I am using Mockito.